# Undefined error when trying to add a product to a cart. Node Js

Tags: node.js, express, nodes

I am learning node js and i am trying to add a product to cart but it's not working and having a error that the price is not define but i have it in my model products. so i don't how to solve the problem. i tried many time but i could not find the right way ro solve it.

My Product File:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const p = path.join(
  path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
  "data",
  "products.json"
);

const getProductsFromFile = (cb) => {
  fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
    if (err) {
      cb([]);
    } else {
      cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
    }
  });
};

module.exports = class Product {
  constructor(title, imageUrl, description, price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
  }

  save() {
    this.id = Math.random().toString();
    getProductsFromFile((products) => {
      products.push(this);
      fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }

  static fetchAll(cb) {
    getProductsFromFile(cb);
  }

  static findById(id, cb) {
    getProductsFromFile((products) => {
      const product = products.find((p) => p.id === id);
      cb(product);
    });
  }
};
```

My Cart.js file

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const p = path.join(
  path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
  "data",
  "cart.json"
);

module.exports = class Cart {
  static addProduct(id, productPrice) {
    // Fetch the previous cart
    fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
      let cart = { products: [], totalPrice: 0 };
      if (!err) {
        cart = JSON.parse(fileContent);
      }
      // Analyze the cart => Find existing product
      const existingProductIndex = cart.products.findIndex(
        (prod) => prod.id === id
      );
      const existingProduct = cart.products[existingProductIndex];
      let updatedProduct;
      // Add new product/ increase quantity
      if (existingProduct) {
        updatedProduct = { ...existingProduct };
        updatedProduct.qty = updatedProduct.qty + 1;
        cart.products = [...cart.products];
        cart.products[existingProductIndex] = updatedProduct;
      } else {
        updatedProduct = { id: id, qty: 1 };
        cart.products = [...cart.products, updatedProduct];
      }
      cart.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice + +productPrice;
      fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

the controller

```
const Product = require("../models/product");
const Cart = require("../models/cart");

exports.postAddToCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  Product.findById(prodId, (product) => {
    Cart.addProduct(prodId, product.price);
  });
  res.redirect("/cart");
};
```

the template file ejs :

```
      <form action="/cart" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="button addToCart">Add to card</button>
        <!-- pass the value using the input hidden -->
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%= product.id %> ">
      </form>
```

the error:
[image]

what i am doing wrong? please help i am just learning. help me. thanks

i tried many time but i could not find the right way to solve it.

Comment: In your `getProductsFromFile` before calling the callback function `cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));` can you `console.log` to check if you are getting the products array

Comment: yes, I am getting the product array.

Comment: You have to do some debugging wherever the products array is being used, like in the `getProductsFromFile` when you are doing the `find` operation, is it giving you a product or not, probably the `productId` input from the `form` does not matches